# Prevent users from deleting their email once entered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model

My Rails (using Rails 5) application is currently set up so that users sign-in/sign-up with their mobile number and a password. This was set up using Devise but changing the authentication_keys to mobile_number rather than email.

There is a form where they can add additional details including an email address.
Currently there is no validation on e-mail as I do not want it to be mandatory to enter one. However, I would like it so that if the user does choose to enter an e-mail address they are unable to go back and delete it (only update it).
There is also this snippet of code in the User model which I thought I could edit to make it require an email when the email field is not blank (but it didn't work):

```
# app/models/user.rb
def email_required?
  false unless email.present?
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `presence` validation with condition to presence of previous email:

```
validates :email, presence: true, if: -> { email_was.present? }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom validation, that will be run upon update:

```
class User
  validate :non_removable_email, on: :update

  private

  def non_removable_email
    return if email_was.nil?

    errors.add(:email, 'Can only be edited') if email.blank?
  end
end
```

Once user hits `Submit` on edit page, the validation is run. If the `email` was never set (eg is `nil`) nothing happens. But if `email` was there but changed to be empty - error will be fired.

Comment: Thanks Andrey, this also worked nicely but I ended up going with Alex's method as it was more succinct

Comment: @cdimitroulas right, with my solution you have more control over validating logic, message etc. But for sure Alex's solution is way to go, don't know how I did not come up with it in the first place :)